# Redirect to a page without Query String using Re-write module in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, url-rewriting

I have to create a Re-write Rule which will redirect a URL as below

abc.com/ssss/aaaaa/fff.aspx/?homeredirect=ture

to

abc.com/ssss/aaaaa/fff.aspx

abc.com/fff.aspx/?homeredirect=ture

to

abc.com/fff.aspx

i am not getting how i can go for this.

i have tried the below one, but it didn't work for me

```
 <rule name="Mb" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url ="^([_A-Z0-9a-z-]+)/?homeredirect=true" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping ="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input ="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?abc.com$"/>
        <add input ="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="ModuleId" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

From URL Rewrite's perspective, the question mark in the "url" attribute is taken to mean "zero or one" in the context of a regular expression.

To use the query string in a rewrite rule, make it a condition. This is similar to mod_rewrite's treatment of the query string in Apache.

Also it's a good idea to escape any character which might have meaning to a regular expression, such as a period.

For IIS URL Rewrite Module:

```
<!-- Remove homeredirect=true from query string for URLs ending in .aspx -->
<rule name="Mb" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <!-- Match any URL ending in ".aspx/" -->
  <match url="\.aspx/$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?abc\.com$" />

    <!-- Match if the query string includes "homeredirect=true" -->
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="homeredirect=true" />
  </conditions>

  <!-- Redirect to the URL without the query string -->
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Have a look at the [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) for more details.